# Transformar MessageDigest MD5 em string

Tags: java, criptografia, md5

Estou tentado gerar um hash MD5 utilizando a classe `MessageDigest`, porém, não consigo exibir corretamente na tela o hash como `String`.

O resultado é uma sequência de caracteres desconhecidos.

Segue abaixo o código de teste:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class TesteMD5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = "teste md5";
       try {
          MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
          md.update(str.getBytes());
          byte[] bytes = md.digest();
          System.out.println("Hash: " + new String(bytes));
       } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

O resultado que eu estou tendo é:

```
Hash: ���9��p>n$�u �
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está retornando a representação em `String` dos `bytes` retornados pelo método do `MessageDigest`. O código para representar o que você quer é este:

```
String original = "teste md5";
try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(original.getBytes());
    byte[] digest = md.digest();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte b : digest)
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
    System.out.println("string original: " + original);
    System.out.println("digested(hex): " + sb.toString());
} catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Você ver e rodar este exemplo aqui: [jdoodle.com/a/Yi](http://jdoodle.com/a/Yi)

A saída será:

```
string original: teste md5
digested(hex): d4d1c93999f913703e6e0524b17520ef
```

Fonte:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-generate-an-md5-digest-for-a-string.html

Answer (score 4):

Este código é o que uso nos meus algoritmos, tente dessa forma:

```
String str = "teste md5";
try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] array = md.digest(str.getBytes());
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1, 3));
    }
    System.out.println("Hash: " + sb.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenta usar o [`DataTypeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html), eu também passaria um encoding para manter o hash portável (`getBytes` assume o *encoding* padrão da plataforma):

```
md.update(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] bytes = md.digest();
System.out.println("Hash: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes));
```

---

**Fonte**: [SOen - Get MD5 String from Message Digest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5470219/664577)

Answer (score 3):

Existe também essa opção:

```
    String s="teste md5";
    MessageDigest m=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    m.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"),0,s.length());
    System.out.println("MD5: " + new BigInteger(1,m.digest()).toString(16));
```

Fonte: [How can I generate a MD5 Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10530959/2236741)